# How to hide lightSlder's nav bar?

Tags: jquery, slider, photo-gallery

How to hide navigation block (bottom part of picture - points) for lightSlider, i need only pictures. I didn't see see standart parameter in lightSlider's docs.

Example with nav bar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3Ydz.png, i need without it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lightSlider property pager: false

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to add a CSS rule for this. Try this.

```
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSpg {
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I found answer. Option pager: false